# How to include QLineEdit in QMessageBox for a search form

Tags: c++, qt

I need to implement a search form (I have already the function), but I don't know how to append (if i can say like that) a QlineEdit and a QPushButton to a QMessageBox.

Answer (score 3):

You could subclass QDialog and use it as a message box

searchdialog.h:

```
#ifndef SEARCHDIALOG_H
#define SEARCHDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QLineEdit>

class SearchDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SearchDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QString searchString() const;

private:
    QLineEdit *m_lineEdit;
};

#endif // SEARCHDIALOG_H
```

searchdialog.cpp

```
#include "searchdialog.h"

#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDialogButtonBox>

SearchDialog::SearchDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent)
{
    m_lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

    QPushButton *searchButton = new QPushButton(tr("Search"));
    searchButton->setDefault(true);

    QPushButton *cancelButton = new QPushButton(tr("Cancel"));

    QDialogButtonBox *buttonBox = new QDialogButtonBox(Qt::Horizontal);
    buttonBox->addButton(searchButton, QDialogButtonBox::AcceptRole);
    buttonBox->addButton(cancelButton, QDialogButtonBox::RejectRole);

    connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(accepted()), this, SLOT(accept()));
    connect(buttonBox, SIGNAL(rejected()), this, SLOT(reject()));

    QVBoxLayout *lt = new QVBoxLayout;
    lt->addWidget(m_lineEdit);
    lt->addWidget(buttonBox);

    setLayout(lt);
}

QString SearchDialog::searchString() const
{
    return m_lineEdit->text();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QMessageBox>

#include <QLabel>

#include "searchdialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QLabel lbl;
    SearchDialog *dialog = new SearchDialog(&lbl);
    lbl.show();

    QString searchString;

    if (dialog->exec()) {
        searchString = dialog->searchString();
        lbl.setText(searchString);
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to play with its layout:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include  <QMessageBox>
#include  <QLineEdit>
#include  <QPushButton>
#include  <QLayout>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        QMessageBox mb;
        QLineEdit le;
        QPushButton bt;

        mb.layout()->addWidget(&bt);
        mb.layout()->addWidget(&le);

        mb.show();
        return app.exec();
    }
```

Comment: mm, tried, but QLineEdit is like a button, that doesnt do anything.

Comment: you have to connect signal from button to any slot of any object you need after that to make it do anything

Comment: but how to access QMessageBox's QLineEdit?  my current is QString searchString = ui->lineEdit->text(); , where lineEdit takes part from ui..

Comment: I think it possible via `le` variable.